# Dynamically load and call delegates based on source data

Tags: c#, dynamic-typing

Assume I have a stream of records that need to have some computation.  Records will have a combination of these functions run `Sum`, `Aggregate`, `Sum over the last 90 seconds`, or `ignore`.

A data record looks like this:

```
Date;Data;ID
```

**Question**

Assuming that ID is an `int` of some kind, and that int corresponds to a matrix of some delegates to run, how should I use C# to dynamically build that launch map?

I'm sure this idea exists... it is used in Windows Forms which has many delegates/events, most of which will never actually be invoked in a real application.

The sample below includes a few delegates I want to run (sum, count, and print) but I don't know how to make the quantity of delegates fire based on the source data.  (say print the evens, and sum the odds in this sample)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
internal static class TestThreadpool
{

    delegate int TestDelegate(int  parameter);

    private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            // this approach works is void is returned.
            //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(PrintOut), "Hello");

            int c = 0;
            int w = 0;
            ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out w, out c);
            bool rrr =ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(w, c);
            Console.WriteLine(rrr);

            // perhaps the above needs time to set up6
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            DateTime ttt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            TestDelegate d = new TestDelegate(PrintOut);

            List<IAsyncResult> arDict = new List<IAsyncResult>();

            int count = 1000000;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                IAsyncResult ar = d.BeginInvoke(i, new AsyncCallback(Callback), d);
                arDict.Add(ar);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                int result = d.EndInvoke(arDict[i]);
            }


            // Give the callback time to execute - otherwise the app
            // may terminate before it is called
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var res = DateTime.UtcNow - ttt;
            Console.WriteLine("Main program done----- Total time --> " + res.TotalMilliseconds);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }


    static int PrintOut(int parameter)
    {
        // Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " Delegate PRINTOUT waited and printed this:"+parameter);
        var tmp = parameter * parameter;
        return tmp;
    }

    static int Sum(int parameter)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Pretend to do some math... maybe save a summary to disk on a separate thread
        return parameter;
    }

    static int Count(int parameter)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Pretend to do some math... maybe save a summary to disk on a separate thread
        return parameter;
    }

    static void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        TestDelegate d = (TestDelegate)ar.AsyncState;
       //Console.WriteLine("Callback is delayed and returned") ;//d.EndInvoke(ar));
    }

}
```

Comment: Not related to you question, but why are you calling `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads()`? I think you should have a very good reason to do that. And of course, calling `Thread.Sleep(1000)` doesn't make sense at all. Also, you should use better variable names than `rrr` and `ttt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assuming that ID is an int of some kind, and that int corresponds to a matrix of some delegates to run, how should I use C# to dynamically build that launch map?

How is that dynamic? It sounds as though you simply want a `Dictionary<int,Func<int,int>>` where the ID is the key and the delegate is the value. Simple function composition (or perhaps just taking advantage of the multicast nature of C# delegates) will handle scenarios where you need multiple effects.

Comment: I haven't used Func<T,T> yet... I suppose this is my time to learn.  Thanks I'll look at it!